# Easiest way to stream S3 file from MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-s3

I have an asp.net MVC app, which currently stores uploaded images and files in an SQL Server FileTable.

When a user requests a file, it streams it directly from the FileTable path, like so...

```
Return New FilePathResult(file_path, content_type)
```

The site uses CloudFront to cache views, files, images etc.

This all works great. It's fast, and robust. However FileTable is a bit problematic for hosting as it isn't support by Azure SQL, or Amazon RDS etc. I would like to transition away from managing my own SQL server instance on the web server.

What I want to do is change over to using S3 for the file and image storage, but still continue to stream the content from MVC. I understand that it probably makes sense long term to serve the files directly from S3, but this will require a fair bit of re-work.

What I'm looking for, is a simple, reliable way to retrieve an object from S3, and then stream it to the browser as a FileResult. I'm not overly concerned about performance, as CloudFront will cache the content anyway.

I tried doing the following...

```
Public Function TestAWS() As FileResult
    Using client As New AmazonS3Client()
        Using _response = client.GetObject(New GetObjectRequest With {.BucketName = "mybucket",.Key = "my_file.txt"})
            Using _stream = _response.ResponseStream
                Return New FileStreamResult(_stream, "text/plain")
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there some way I can take the S3 stream, and somehow just copy it directly to the controller output stream?

Is what I'm doing actually possible, or do I need to save the file locally, and then return that using FilePathResult?

Update: I ended up just saving the file locally, before returning it with FilePathResult. This also gives me the opportunity to cache the files, to slightly improve performance.

Comment: Did you take a look at AWS SDK for .NET ?

Comment: What should I be looking for in the AWS SDK?